# Выполнение <script> При определенном class

Tags: javascript, html, классы, списки

Есть связанные выпадающие списки и во втором списке к первому присвоен `class`. Как сделать чтобы скрипт js выполнялся только при определенном значении `class`?
Эти 2 кода(выпадающий список и JS код с выводом актуальной даты) по отдельности все рабочие. Мне же нужно сделать связку чтобы если я выбирал определенное значение во втором выпадающем списке(допустим с `class="chiv"`), то 2(который JS) код начинал работать и выводил свою картинку(в итоге должно показывать два изображения, одно от выпадающего списка и одно от JS кода). Если же с другим class, то JS код бы просто пропускался.

```html
<select id="programming">
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="chiv">Животные</option>
  <option value="ptic">Птицы</option>
  <option value="rast">Растения</option>
</select>
<select id="categories">
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="img\зебра.jpg" class="chiv">Зебра</option>
  <option value="img\лев.jpg"class="chiv">Лев</option>
   <option value="img\аист.jpg" class="ptic">Аист</option>
   <option value="img\дуб.jpg" class="rast">Дуб</option>
</select>
```

И вот JS код

```html
<script>
  var day=new Date();
    var pictures = ['Sunday.png',
                  'Monday.png',
          'Tuesday.png',
          'Wednesday.png',
          'Thursday.png',
          'Friday.png',
                  'Saturday.png'];
   document.write('<img src="' + pictures[day.getDay()] +'">'); 
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать проверку на `class`, и при `true` выполнять функцию. Можно сделать проверку не по `class`, а по `option`, разницы особой не вижу, с этим кстати проще будет.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213620/how-to-check-if-an-option-is-selected

http://jquery-docs.ru/traversing/is/

Comment: А как сделать по class проверку?